# Will Yosemite Server backup 8.1 work on Windows Server 2008 R2 to backup Exchange 2010?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, barracuda, backup

I've inherited the backup support of some Windows server 2003 machines that used Yosemite Server backup 8.1

The company has joined the BizSpark program and want to use the license of Windows Server 2008 R2 and Exchange 2010.

I've tried to email barracuda who took over Yosemite to ask this but with no success. (do you need a support contract?)

I don't have a spare machine or even space for a VM to test it on, does anybody know it it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer back from Barracudaware support on this so thought as nobody has answered I’ll fill in the blanks.

It seems that Yosemite Backup 8.1 only supports NT, Server 2000, Windows XP and Server 2003.

Yosemite Backup 8.1 service pack 6, does support Windows Server 2008 but not Exchange 2010.

So, in order for me to backup Exchange 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Yosemite Backup I need to upgrade to 8.9.